# Migrating CXF web service app to WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: cxf, websphere-8

I am in the process of migrating an application which is deployed on WAS 6.1. It's CXF based web services compatible with Java 1.5 (developed on JDK 1.4). It needs to be migrated/deployed on WAS 8.5.5.9.

Will I be needing any kind of code changes or configuration changes will be enough?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest hurdle will probably be the fact that WAS now includes its own web services libraries (that wasn't added to 6.1 until a feature pack), so you'll need to do a bit of configuration to use a third-party web services implementation.  The official doc is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

The most important things:

1) Set a property to disable WebSphere's JAX-WS engine

2) Make sure that your CXF implementation and JAX-WS API are packaged in a PARENT_LAST class loader (a loader that searches locally before delegating to its parents, to keep you from picking up WebSphere's JAX-WS runtime).  The doc recommends setting your web module class loader to PARENT_LAST, but it'd be even safer to put the CXF/JAX-WS jars into a shared library with the "use an isolated class loader" option, which will cause just those specific jars to be loaded in that manner.

Comment: Thank you Jarid for your reply. I'll update this post how it goes in next few days.

Comment: Just want to point out, though, if your application is coded to only use the APIs, not anything CXF-specific, you might not have to disable the WAS-provided version(s).

Comment: In that case, you could also just use the WAS-provided API and not bother with packaging CXF at all.  If you are dead-set on CXF for whatever reason, then I think the "disable" property is mandatory - if you don't do that, the WAS provider will perform annotation scanning, and you run the risk of stuff like LinkageErrors due to WebSphere and the app having visibility to separate copies of the API.